# In Grails how to parse and redirect based on the hash code in the URL?

Tags: grails

If I have a URL like:

www.example.com/?state=1#app/itemSearch?q=apple&cat=books&pg=1

In my grails application if the server detects above URL, it should redirect to:

www.example.com/app/itemSearch?q=apple&cat=books&pg=1

How can I do that?

Assume the controller name is main and action is index to serve request for /. So the above logic would be in this controller and action.

Comment: FYI - The bit after the # is never sent to the server, only the browser and client-side scripts see it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In that case if it is true that nothing after # is sent to the server then I will have to change URL to look like: www.example.com/?state=1app/itemSearch?q=apple&cat=books&pg=1

Comment: Be careful, I think it is invalid for a url to have multiple multiple question marks. Your server may be able to do a rewrite to cope with it, but other applications may not handle such a url in the way you would expect.

Comment: Your URL should be something like  www.example.com/app/itemSearch?state=1&q=apple&cat=books&pg=1

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the "Fragment identifier" (Hash) for this purpose because its processing is exclusively client-side with no participation from the web server. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

You should send the url by parameter enconding this way:

```
def encondedUrl = java.net.URLEncoder.encode("www.example.com/app/itemSearch?q=apple&cat=books&pg=1")
```

[Wikipedia Fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)